# UIImagePickerController screen issue in iOS 8+ for iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-4

I am working on the universal application. I have implemented image picker and code for it is as bellow.

```
 isimagepiking=TRUE;
imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
NSArray *mediaTypesAllowed = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.image"];
[imgPicker setMediaTypes:mediaTypesAllowed];
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imgPicker.wantsFullScreenLayout=true;
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    [self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Bellow code print **480** as size.

```
 NSLog(@"%f",imgPicker.view.frame.size.height);
```

This things works fine in iphone 5+ with ios 8.3 and in iphone 4 below ios 7.1, But in **iphone 4s** for **ios 8+** picker doesn't show **Choose** and **Cancel** button

Screen with ios 7.1 iphone 4s.
[image: iOS 7.1 iPhone 4s screen-- This works fine]

Screen With iOS 8.2 iPhone 4s -- Not showing **Choose** or **Cancel** button
[image: Screen With iOS 8.2 iPhone 4s -- Not working properly]

It seems like in iOS 8+ it take the uiscreen size as 4 inch.
Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check the size of self.view. It should be of 4 inch height.

Comment: @Ritu thanks for comment... I did checked it view size is as expected at time of presenting pickerview

Comment: @Ritu at time of dismiss self.view size is 568 which is as expected for iphone 4s

Answer (score 0):

I hope Presenting the view is making the problem. Try addSubview

```
isimagepiking=TRUE;
    imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    NSArray *mediaTypesAllowed = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"public.image"];
    [imgPicker setMediaTypes:mediaTypesAllowed];
    imgPicker.delegate = self;
    imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imgPicker.wantsFullScreenLayout=true;

    //  Try Adding imagepicker as a subview
    [self createAnimationsinView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:imgPicker.view] ;
```

If you want a present view controller animation, that can also be done.

//    Present view controller Animation

```
-(void)createAnimationsinView:(UIView*)view{
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromTop;
    [view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. This did worked but i have Tabbar at bottom so again cancel and choose button doesn't show up.

Comment: have you tried setting the size of the imagePicker to self.view.bounds?